# Check whether compiler is nightly at compile time

Tags: rust

That is it: how do I know whether the project is building by nightly or stable compiler? Something like this:

```
#[cfg(nightly_build)]
use std::ptr::Shared; // on nightly use system's version

#[cfg(not(nightly_build))]
use myshared::Shared; // on stable use my unoptimized Shared
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with the [rustc_version](https://crates.io/crates/rustc_version) crate and a build.rs script:

```
extern crate rustc_version;
use rustc_version::{version_meta, Channel};

fn main() {
    // Set cfg flags depending on release channel
    match version_meta().unwrap().channel {
        Channel::Stable => {
            println!("cargo:rustc-cfg=RUSTC_IS_STABLE");
        }
        Channel::Beta => {
            println!("cargo:rustc-cfg=RUSTC_IS_BETA");
        }
        Channel::Nightly => {
            println!("cargo:rustc-cfg=RUSTC_IS_NIGHTLY");
        }
        Channel::Dev => {
            println!("cargo:rustc-cfg=RUSTC_IS_DEV");
        }
    }
}
```

Then check it with `#[cfg(feature = "RUSTC_IS_STABLE")]`, etc in the Rust code.

Answer (score 4):

There are two options that I'm aware of.

1.
Use a feature for this in your [Cargo.toml](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/blob/d6de911855d1cc0ad13f87503a79d40dc4490442/serde/src/lib.rs#L103) and use it in your code like this: [`#![cfg_attr(feature = "unstable", feature(nonzero, specialization))]`](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/blob/master/serde/src/lib.rs#L89)

2.
Use a build.rs file and check the environment variable [CFG_RELEASE_CHANNEL](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rls/blob/master/build.rs#L38). Beware, that I can't find it in the official [Documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html), so try it out beforehand.

Comment: I think the better approach is to run `rustc --version -v` and  parse output (btw this is exactly what `rustc_version` does)